# Найти наименьшее число кратное К

Tags: python, python-3.x

Дано натуральное число K. Найти наименьшее число кратное К, все цифры которого одинаковы (пользуемся, конечно, десятичной системой счисления).
Вы вводите с клавиатуры число K (2 <= K <= 1000). Вы выводите на экран цифру i
количество этих цифр в числе. Если решения не существует, вывести 0 0.
Пример.

Введение:

```
37
```

Вывод:

```
1 3
```

Comment: Нашел, что то с ним нужно делать? (**где ваш код? сделать за вас?**)

Comment: Я новичек в програмировании и не могу понять эту задачу, и прошу помоч мне в ней разобраться.

Comment: омг, а почему вы указываете, как результат [1, 3]? 37 - простое число вроде, тогда по вашей логике, ответ должен быть [0, 3], иначе везде будет единица, ибо, все натуральные числа делятся на неё...

Comment: @JackWolf три единицы - `111 / 37 = 3`

Comment: Вам нужно найти наименьшее число(назовем его X), которое будет без остатка делится на K(37), при этом все цифры числа X должны быть одинаковы, из вашего примера X=111, K= 37, вывод приложения 1 3(единица три раза)

Comment: Мне интересно, как Вы будете определять, что "развязку не существует".

Comment: @Igor Получением периодического кратного?(92929292(92)) пример K=50 =)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков При делении чего на что?

Comment: Задачу я взял с етого сайта https://new.netoi.org.ua/index_ua.php?lng=ua&cid=771

Comment: @Igor Найдите решение для K=50, отвечу сразу - его нет. как и для любого К кратного 10 =) p.s. задачка похоже олимпиадная, и имеет тривиальное решения =) мне оно не известно, но если полчасика подумать - решаемо

Comment: @Igor решение в лоб, перебор со всеми простыми множителями меньше K. дальнейший перебор не имеет значение, т.к. результат не будет меняться в нужную сторону.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Перебор чего?

Comment: @Igor, подумал про перебор простых множителей Y(где Y<K): X(111)=K(37)*Y(3), но с ограничением на Y<K, пропускаем часть решений, без ограничения - имеем бесконечный цикл перебора.... надо вспомнить все теории простых чисел чтоб точно найти верхнюю границу поиска множителя

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Итак, число должно делиться на `K` без остатка. Значит число итоговое должно быть равно `N = K*x`, где `х` - это какое-то любое число.

Вывод: в цикле умножаем `K` на `x`, начиная с `2`, до бесконечности (или предела, какой вам нужен), для каждого числа проверяем равны ли десятки, сотни, тысячи и т.д. (делается через целочисленное деление), если равны, то выводим это число и выходим из цикла. Всё.

Comment: Сколько времени вы будете умножать до бесконечности, чтобы понять, что для числа, например, 20 решения не существует?

Comment: в теории конечно можно добавить проверку для входного числа и все  с нулями в конце убирать(потому что число с нулём в конце всегда при умножении даёт в конце 0, а значит нам нужно число вида 000000, а таких не бывает), но задача была вроде просто решить, а не максимально эффективно

Comment: Ну так и как вы решите со своим алгоритмом задачу при входном числе 20?

Comment: когда дойдет до максимума скажу что такого числа нет))

Comment: тут возникает два вопроса: как понять, что уже максимум? Какой максимум в питоне? Странно, что этот совершенно непригодный для решения задачи ответ еще и помечен как принятый.

Comment: потому что это совершенно годный для решения задачи ответ... Какой максимум нужен для решения пусть человек решает сам, я не хочу давать полный и развернутый ответ просто студенту который не хочет сам подумать как решить задачу

Comment: В задаче максимум вообще не фигурирует. Или да или нет. А вы в поисках решения и в ожидании максимума будете умножать 20 на х до скончания веков, пока процессор не истлеет.

Answer (score 0):

Вот простое переборное решение

Рассмотрим число aaa..aa оно равно a*(111..11)

1. Для чисел меньше 10 всегда ответ n 2
2. Если число делится на цифру и получается нечетное, то может быть решение
3. Если число делится на цифру и всегда остается четное, то нельзя

   ```
   def getNumber(n, max_iter):
       if n < 10:
             print(n, 2)
             return
         a = 10
         flag = 0
         # Если возможно поделить на однозначное и получится нечетное число
       while (a >= 2) and (flag == 0):
          a = a - 1
          if n % a == 0:
             if n // a % 2 != 0:
                n = n // a
                flag = 1
       # Если a=1, то нельзя
       # Если a>1, то это цифра на которую умножаем 1111.111
       if a==1 and n%2==0:
         print(0,0)
         return
       r = 111
       t = 3
       while t <= max_iter:
          if r % n == 0:
             print(a, t)
             return
          else:
             r = 10 * r + 1
          t=t+1
       if t > max_iter:
          print(0, 0)


    getNumber(32,20)
   ```

Comment: сделайте, пожалуйста, нестрогое условие [while t <= max_iter], ведь если, вы введёте, например, (37, 3), то результат будет неверный

Comment: @JackWolf согласен, исправил. Но мы разумно понимаем, что количетсво итераций "большое".

Comment: ага, разумеется-

Comment: Решение для чисел меньше 10 - неверное,для ввода 2 ваш вариант выдаст 22, а должно быть 4